# Google Graphs show decimal places on scatter points

Tags: javascript, graph, google-visualization, jsfiddle

I have created a scatter chart using the Google Graphs API and all is fine apart from the fact that it will only so scatter points as decimal places if they're less than 10.

[Here's the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jampez77/frtjawse/)

```
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['scatter']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart () {

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["Period", "C Spencer Ltd"],
    ["1", -11.4],["2", 36.7],
    ["3", null],
    ["4", null],
    ["5", null]
]);

  var options = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Scoring Trends',
      subtitle: '*All LAG scores validated from Period 4'
    },
    width: 900,
    height: 500
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Scatter(document.getElementById('full_stacked_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);

}
```

I've tried using the NumberFormatter and the vAxis.format [shown here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/scatterchart?hl=en) all with no joy.

Comment: verified and stumped

Comment: welcome to my world :/. Thanks for having a look though. appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `google.charts.Scatter.convertOptions(options)` in your draw (`chart.draw(data, google.charts.Scatter.convertOptions(options));`) when working with material charts, otherwise options like `format` won't work.

See the bottom part of [Material Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/scatterchart?hl=en#creating-material-scatter-charts) section.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frtjawse/1/) with the option `vAxis:{format:'decimal'}` to accomplish what you're requesting.

EDIT:

Just want to note that this is a very common mistake and maybe someone should try to push google the emphasize the importance of this.